# Inductance of solenoid with solid metal core

Tags: inductor, frequency, inductance, solenoid

Consider the solenoid/inductor like in the picture.

[image: Fig 1]

There is an air gap between the coil and the inserted solid metal.

The solid metal is from aluminum or copper (Both have a relative magnetic permeability close to 1 regardless of temperature).

What will happen with the inductance of the given solenoid if we increase the frequency of the applied voltage?

If we increase f , will the Inductance increase too? Thanks.

Comment: Fan - Hi, Please add a [reference / citation](/help/referencing) for the copied image, as required by the site rules. If the source is online then add the name of the webpage / PDF document / video and its link. For an offline source (e.g. book), then add a normal citation - see that site rule for details. TY

Answer (score 1):

Induced eddy currents in the core partially cancel the magnetic flux of the coil. That's a direct consequence of Lenz's Law. Thus inserting the conductive core reduces the coil inductance - that's because the magnetic flux of the coreless coil is I * L  where I is the current through the coil and L is the inductance of the coil. When the flux is partially cancelled by the eddy currents, the effect to the total flux is like the inductance was reduced.

This is actually utilized in making adjustable inductors. The core has been a copper or aluminium screw. The drawback is that the amount of the wire in the coil is substantially higher than in coils where the adjustable core is made of ferrite or glued iron powder.

Calculating exactly the effect of a core is extremely complex. Only some coarse design formulas are possible. Accurate analysis needs numerical physics simulation and exact knowledge of the dimensions and materials.  Without such simulation software the only practical way to find the effect of the core is to make measurements.

**Frequency and the effect of the conductive core**

If we consider the core as a shorted secondary in a loose transformer the effective inductance is L(1-k^2) where L is the inductance of the coreless coil and k is the magnetic coupling factor (the proportion of the common part of the flux) between the core and the plain coil.

This does not mean that the inductance reduction does not depend on the frequency. The skin effect makes the current zone in the core surface thinner as the frequency grows. Thus the effective shorted loop diameter caused by the core increases and the coupling factor k grows. Thus the growth of the frequency reduces the effective inductance. But that assumes the thinning of the skin depth does not increase the resistance so much that the shorting effect of the core is reduced. The actual weights of the opposite consequences of the frequency growth cannot be decided  better without making measurements or a physics simulation just in the special case under the interest.

Comment: So , in general if we increase frequency for given Solenoid/Inductor we increase The value for L?

Comment: As the other answer says indirectly, the effect of the inductance decreases when the frequency is reduced. Thus the effect of the core is also reduced. I wrote the same in my original version, but seemingly that's not interesting. So I removed that duplicate and inserted a paragraph with some numerical reasoning of the effects of increasing the frequency.

Comment: Thanks. And for the given scenario Solenoid with metal solid if increase frequency, we will increase the inductive reactance (impedance) too ?

Comment: Increasing the frequency reduces the inductance (assuming the resistance of the thinned core skin area stays neglible) But the growth of the frequency increases the reactance of the inductor (=2Pi * f * L). I cannot say a generally valid rule which of the effects win when one wants to know does the growth of the frequency increase the reactance of an inductor with conductive core. Measure it for your solenoid device at the interesting frequency. There's also the capacitances between the turns which affect the reactance.

Comment: Thanks . About Inductive reactance we will have increase with increasing frequency Even in the current scenario with eddy currents and solid metal core? Lets consider relative magnetic permeability of the core is always 1 , regardless of the temperature?

Comment: How did you eliminate the effect of the capacitance which makes the device a tricky resonant circuit - high impedance at certain resonant frequencies. A parallel LC circuit have only one such resonant frequency, but this one can have many of them.

Comment: No it is only general question about inductor on the picture. what will happen with Ind. Reactance if we increase frequency ? I didnt perform any tests?

Comment: @unawriter "the other answer" did not say (directly of indirectly) "the effect of the inductance decreases when the frequency is reduced" and, not only did I not say it but, I wouldn't say it either.

Comment: @Andyaka Ok, You said "Inductive reactance, is wholly dependent on frequency" I only imagined you kept also X=2Pi * f * L an useful relation. But that really was imagination. I apologize.

Comment: @Fan the inductance L is reduced due the eddy currents in the core as the frequency grows if it happens that the thinning of the skin area do not reduce too much the eddy currents (due the resistance growth). The reactance 2Pi * f * L grows as the frequency grows, but it can happen that the inductance L is reduced so much that the reactance doesn't grow. Finally there can be complex LC resonances which affect the total reactance radically even in case the core affects nothing. Too complex for any rule of thumb! Measure and know what the measured device does. Other devices work differently.

Answer (score 1):

> *If we increase f , will the Inductance increase too?*

Inductance is largely based on a coil or transformer's physical geometry and materials hence, is not affected by applied frequency. It's not based on the conductivity of the coil either. Some ferrite core materials (if used) can change their permeability at higher frequencies but, your model doesn't appear to include them. Some LCR measurement meters may display effective series inductance at some frequencies and, effective parallel inductance at different frequencies so, beware.

Inductive reactance, on the other hand, is wholly dependent on frequency.

Comment: And for the given scenario Solenoid with metal solid if increase frequency, we will increase the inductive reactance too ?

Comment: That's what I'm saying @Fan

Comment: Thanks. Great. Just to ask You are sure or you suppose. Will be great if you are sure about this.

Comment: @Fan there will be minor influences due to skin and proximity effects.

Comment: Inductance in general is a function of frequency; good inductors are close to constant, but in general it can vary, generally decreasing as frequency rises. A necessary consequence of which is resistance, loss (via Kramers-Kronig relations).

Comment: Please also consider Eddy currents in the metal core.

Answer (score 0):

In general, inserting some conductive loading material reduces inductance.

This is easy to see by considering the effect at extreme frequencies.  Real components have impedance continuous with respect to frequency, therefore we can apply the intermediate value theorem to make basic conclusions about it.

At DC, the material has no impact on the magnetic field -- assuming it's nonmagnetic like copper or aluminum, and ignoring the minute effect of para/diamagnetism.  Inductance is thus nominal.  Not that you have any reactance at exactly DC, of course, and nevermind that resistance dominates -- but we aren't concerned about |Z| here, only Im(Z), and the limit as frequency approaches DC.

At high frequency, skin depth is much thinner than the diameter of the material -- which is to say, magnetic field is excluded from the center.  This reduces the cross section, which means less total flux from the same magnetization, and thus less inductance.  The loading can be treated as a shorted turn of a transformer, reducing the inductance of the primary from its self-inductance, to the leakage inductance between the windings.

Because impedance is continuous, we can conclude that, for intermediate frequencies, inductance can be expressed as a function of frequency, having a larger value at low frequencies, and a smaller value at high frequencies.

---

We can conclude additionally that resistance is a factor in (and around) the transition region.  Impedance is not just continuous, but also an analytic function of frequency, therefore Kramers-Kronig relations stipulate that the real and imaginary components cannot behave arbitrarily or independently, but exhibit this relationship.  In short: a decreasing inductance corresponds to some amount of resistance.

Note that a solid nonmagnetic metal exhibits skin effect, i.e. magnetic field diffuses into it.  Diffusion, as a physical phenomena, means depth varies as \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{f}}\$, and so too the impedance -- and resistance and inductance (give or take a factor of f).  That is, we have a [Warburg element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warburg_element), with \$L \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{f}}\$, \$|Z| \propto \sqrt{f}\$, \$R = X\$, and \$\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}\$ (all of which are equivalent descriptions, due to K-K relations).

Since the skin depth pushes magnetic field out of the bulk of the load material, it's not like it can push any further outward than its boundary; as a result, at some point, the change in inductance slows down, and Q factor (Q = X/R) goes back up again.  At high enough frequencies, such a coil can still be useful as a tuning element, for example; this is the regime in which [unawriter's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/697616/311631) mentions, that is, using a metal slug to tune an inductor.  We can conclude, such a mechanism is not helpful at lower frequencies where the skin depth (into the slug) is significant.